# Do I need to file taxes in a specific state if a small portion of my income was paid by a company based there?

Tags: united-states, taxes, self-employment, state-taxes

I am a resident of New York for tax purposes, but conducted a small amount of freelance work with a company based in California in 2018.

They issued payment via direct deposit and my bank information includes my New York address – do I need to file CA taxes in addition to NY taxes for this?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, if this is freelance income (i.e. no additional benefits aside from the payment for services rendered) and you're below the filing threshold (see links below), no you don't need to file a CA tax return. Assuming that you meet the requirements though, you'd be looking for Form 540NR.

References:
[CA Non-Resident Filing Requirements](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2018-california-tax-rates-and-exemptions.shtml#ifr)
[California Non-Resident Filing Thresholds](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2018-california-tax-rates-and-exemptions.shtml#ifr)